# Removing Column names using like operator in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where most of the column names are as below:

```
tre_ui_1920
tre_ui_2221
tre_ui_8989
```

and something like

```
foo_bar_123
foo_bar_456
```

I want to delete all the columns belonging to `foo_bar_*` and `tre_ui_*`

I have seen few codes in R which suggest to use subset and indexing.
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Try `i1 <- !grepl("foo_bar_|tre_ui_", names(df1)); df1[i11]`

Comment: It's easier to help if you include [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), particularly a sample of data, but also what you've tried that hasn't worked. You say "is there any better way," so what are those ways that haven't worked so far? How does this differ from similar questions elsewhere?

Comment: For example, here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51846437/5325862

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grepl` to return a logical index based on the patterns in the column names

```
i1 <- !grepl("foo_bar_|tre_ui_", names(df1))
subdf1 <- df1[i11]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done in `dplyr`:

```
dat %>% select(matches("foo_bar_|tre_ui_"))
```